# Lines with irrational slope in a torus

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying understand one point about Example 15.9 in the Introduction to Manfolds by Tu (p. 167). I'll reproduce the example here. See this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016171/example-15-9-in-loring-tus-an-introduction-to-manifolds), which addressed a separate question I had.

> *Example* 15.9 (*Lines with irrational slope in a torus*). Let $G$ be the torus $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $L$ a line through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The torus can also be represented by the unit square with the opposite edges identified. The image $H$ of $L$ under the projection $\pi:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a closed curve if and only if the line $L$ goes through another lattice point, say $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$. This is the case if and only if the slope of $L$ is $n/m$, a rational number or $\infty$; then $H$ is the image of finitely many line segments on the unit square. It is a closed curve diffeomorphic to a circle and is a regular submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ (Figure 15.1).

> If the slope of L is irrational, then its image H on the torus will never close up. **In
> this case the restriction to L of the projection map, $f := \pi\big|_L : L \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$, is a one-to-one
> immersion**. We give H the topology and manifold structure induced from f.

1. I don't understand why $f$ is an immersion. How would I prove this?
2. Why is the subspace topology of H in $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ a *strict* subset of the  topology on $H$ induced from $ f : L \xrightarrow{\sim} H$? For the induced topology, I understand that a basic open set of H is the image under $f$ of an open set in $L$. I also understand that basic open sets in the subspace topology will be the intersection of H with the image of an open ball in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: What is your definition of immersion? If it's a differentiable function whose is everywhere injection, it's just a matter of showing that the tangent map $T_x \pi\vert_L$ is not zero for any $x$.

Comment: Yes that's the definition I intended, that the pushforward is injective. How do I show this?

Comment: Here's one possible outline: (1) The inclusion $\iota: L \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^2$ is an immersion. (2) The quotient map $\pi: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2 / \Bbb Z^2$ has discrete kernel so its differential is an isomorphism, and in particular $\pi$ is an immersion. (3) The composition of two immersions is an immersion.

Comment: Your first point is very clear thanks! But why does a quotient map with a discreet kernel imply the differential is an isomorphism? Can you address my question 2?

Comment: Since the kernel is discrete, around every point $x \in \Bbb R^2$ is a neighborhood $U$ such that $\pi\vert_U$ is a diffeomorphism, so $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism. As for (2), your answer is essentially contained in your question: You just have to show that every open set in the subspace topology is also open in the induced topology, and it suffices to show the claim for an arbitrary intersection $f(L) \cap f(B)$.

Comment: (1) I see that if the kernel is discrete, for each $x \in \mathbb{R^2}$, there's a neighborhood U where either $\pi\vert_U$ is injective (if $x$ is not in the kernel) or otherwise has only one nonzero element in the kernel. Why does this make the Jacobian invertible? (2) Re induced topology. For L, I believe we use the subspace topology under $\mathbb{R^2}$. Then if $U \in \tau_L$, $U = L \cap V$ some $V \in \mathbb{R^2}$. But then $f(U) = f(L) \cap f(V) = H \cap f(V)$, which equals the union of basic open sets in the subspace topology of H -- I must be confused somewhere here?

Comment: For (2), I meant to ask why $\tau_{subspace} \subsetneq \tau_{induced}$.

Comment: @TravisWillse: Regarding question 1, your comments would make a good answer.

Comment: Regarding question 2, you can find an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537125/dense-curve-on-torus-not-an-embedded-submanifold?rq=1).

Comment: @Lee Mosher, can you help address my question about (1)? I still don't quite follow (2), per the point I made yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I don't understand why f is an immersion. How would I prove this?

**Hint** Here's a brief outline:

1. The inclusion $\iota :L \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^2$ is an immersion.
2. The map $\pi: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2 / \Bbb Z^2$ is a covering map. In particular, it is a local diffeomorphism and hence an immersion.
3. The composition of immersions is again an immersion.

> 2. Why is the subspace topology of H in $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ a *strict* subset of the  topology on $H$ induced from $ f : L \xrightarrow{\sim} H$? For the induced topology, I understand that a basic open set of H is the image under $f$ of an open set in $L$. I also understand that basic open sets in the subspace topology will be the intersection of H with the image of an open ball in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

See the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537125/dense-curve-on-torus-not-an-embedded-submanifold?rq=1) mentioned by Lee Mosher. In particular, if we pick an open ball $B \subset \Bbb R^2$ that intersects $L$, then $\pi(B \cap L)$ is by definition open in the subset topology, but any neighborhood (in the subspace topology) of any point in $\pi(B \cap L)$ contains the image of points in $L$ that are not in $\pi(B \cap L)$, hence $\pi(B \cap L)$ is not open in the subspace topology.

Comment: Your explanation of part 2 finally clicked, thanks! I still don't understand why the map in 2. is a local diffeomorphism, however. I see that if the kernel is discrete, for each $x \in R^2$, there's a neighborhood $U$ where either $\pi\vert_U$ is injective (if $x$ is not in the kernel) or otherwise has only one nonzero element in the kernel. Why does this make the Jacobian invertible?

Comment: The map $\pi \vert_U$ is injective regardless of whether $x$ is in the kernel of the quotient map (i.e., has integer coordinates). Injectivity alone is not enough to make the $\pi \vert_U$ smooth, let alone a diffeomorphism (consider $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, $x \mapsto x^{1/3}$), though it's adequate for quotients of Lie groups. Are you familiar with the language of covering maps? If so, it's probably most straightforward to think of $\pi$ as one.

Comment: As best I can tell, the Tu Manifolds book doesn't address covering maps, so I'm not familiar with this. I think I have 2 points of confusion. (1) $\pi\vert_U$ is injective. If U is a neighborhood around a point in $\mathbb{Z^2}$, then the kernel is non-trivial so the map can't be injective. (2) I couldn't find a proof to this claim: If a quotient of a lie group (mod a closed normal subgroup) has an injective projection, its projection is locally diffeomorphic.

Comment: So I don't understand (1), but fairly sure I understand (2) now. Represent $\pi$ by a right group action by the additive group $\mathbb{Z^2}$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$. I know this makes $\pi$ an open map. Thus $\pi$ is bicontinuous and surjective, so you only need injectivity to have a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Ah of course, $\pi\vert_{U}$ has at most one element in the kernel, so it is injective. I understand everything now, so accepting the answer. @Travis Willse thanks so much for the patient explanations!

Comment: @IsaacR24 You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful. To be precise, you need that $\pi\vert_U$ is bicontinuous (and also smooth), but those are both nearly automatic.